# Creating instances of revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to understand how create different instances of revealing module pattern. I have a code block below and create module1 and module2  instances of myRevealingModule and setting their name variables.But name of module1 is overwritten by module2. How can i have different name values for module1 and module2? What am i missing? Thanks!

```
var myRevealingModule = (function(){

    var name = 'Default';

    function setName (nameVal) {
       name = nameVal;
    };

    function getName () {
       return name;
    };

    return {
        fullName: name,
        set: setName,
        get: getName
    };

}());
var module1  = myRevealingModule;
module1.set("module1 name");
var module2  = myRevealingModule;
module2.set("module2 name");
```

Comment: All three variables, `myRevealingModule`, `module1` and `module2` hold references to the very same object. Looks like you are not looking for a module here, but rather a **constructor**, especially when you're talking about "instances". Modules are singleton objects.

Comment: Is it only way using a constructor to have 2 different modules by myRevealingModule? Could i create function callbacks for module1 and module2 to set name values? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need a constructor or factory that is capable of creating multiple objects (if you don't want to copy your code).

Comment: I think factory works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To make multiple instances, you have to remove the `()` at the end of the definition, so that you can call it separately each time you want to create a new instance.  See the code comments in the block below for the three places a change was made:

```
var myRevealingModule = (function(){

    var name = 'Default';

    function setName (nameVal) {
       name = nameVal;
    };

    function getName () {
       return name;
    };

    return {
        fullName: name,
        set: setName,
        get: getName
    };

});    // removed the () here

var module1  = myRevealingModule();    // added () here to call factory function
module1.set("module1 name");
var module2  = myRevealingModule();    // added () here to call factory function
module2.set("module2 name");
```

This makes `myRevealingModule()` into a factory function.  Each time you call it, it creates a new instance of your object.